# CSS: is it possible to make outline border-radius? circle shape in a square shape image

Tags: html, css, button, hover

I am trying to make a menu with square shape and I wanna add a circle box shadow. similar to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1owT.png

but instead it's coming something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGUWt.png

and if I add border-radius is like this and it's not what I am looking for:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HdwlW.png.

this is the code I am using:

```css
nav .nav-right-section .menu-icon {
    background-image: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/41236/dots-menu.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav .nav-right-section .menu-icon:hover {
    background-color: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to wrap the icon with another div.

Then do the border radius only on this wrapper div.

```css
nav .menu-icon-container {
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 16px;
}

nav .menu-icon-container .menu-icon {
    background-image: url('https://www.svgrepo.com/show/41236/dots-menu.svg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

nav .menu-icon-container:hover {
    background-color: rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 20px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 12px rgba(196, 196, 196, 0.131);
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="nav-right-section">
    <div class="menu-icon-container">
      <div class="menu-icon">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
<nav>
```